# Laravel Valet 403 forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet, valet

I am having issues with setting up Laravel Valet on my machine (MacOS Mojave 10.14). I followed the official documentation on [Laravel documentation site](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet). I have installed Valet, added Composer to path, I can run `valet` and `laravel` commands from anywhere in the system so that works. I have mapped my project folder with `valet park`. I can also do a ping on any `*.test` domain and it returns `127.0.0.1` responses.

I have created a new project `laravel new blog` within that directory and when accessing `http://blog.test` I am getting nginx 403 forbidden response.

I suspect something may conflict maybe so I tried these steps, none of which worked:

1. Added explicitly both `blog` and `blog/public` to `valet link blog` and `valet link blog2`. Accessing `blog.test` and `blog2.test` both return forbidden
2. Killing Apache with `sudo apachectl stop` returns:

> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

3. `sudo killall httpd` returns:

> No matching processes were found

4. Uninstalling nginx and running `valet install` again didn't help.
5. Running `sudo nginx` returns:

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
>
> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
>
> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
>
> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
>
> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
>
> nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()

---

**NOTE:** I do have a Docker running on my machine

Comment: Did you install `httpd` from homebrew? Check using `brew services list`

Comment: I didn't have it, now installed but nothing changed

Comment: No, I was not expecting you to install `httpd`. I just want to confirm that Apache isn't turned on, on your machine as Port 80 was being used. I see you have found your answer below now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found Docker to be the issue. I already had an app running on port 80 so it was preventing nginx from starting. I shut down the container and run `sudo nginx` and it solved the issue.